# How to Dynamically Show Hide the Toolbar in Telerik

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

In my Asp.net MVC project i need to Show/Hide or Disable/Enable the Telerik ReportView Toolbar. I need to do this dynamically by using the code. 
This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjS0H.png) contains the section i need to Show/Hide in report.How to do.Any one try to help me.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the client side with style.display = "none"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var RPToolbar = document.getElementById("provide the ID of the html element of the toolbar");
            RPToolbar.style.display = "none";
 </script>
```

Comment: I am using Telerik webviewer report. is this code work for that